# Azure Service Bus Exception on SubscriptionClient Rule

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I am using the Azure Service Bus cloud service and the Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus 3.2.0 NuGet package. I am working with the topic.

When i ad  SubscriptionClient rule for filter the messages like this:

```
 _subscriptionClient.AddRuleAsync(new RuleDescription
                    {
                        Filter = new CorrelationFilter { Label = eventName },
                        Name = eventName
                    }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

I got the message:

> The messaging entity
>   'busName:Topic:topicName~95|subscriptionName|NewOrderEvent' already
>   exists. TrackingId:abd52-f862bcb97538_B28,
>   SystemTracker:NoSystemTracker, Timestamp:2018-12-04T22:42:12
>   Reference:8dd88c32c3b5, TrackingId:a872a63e-9917-4d131_G22,
>   SystemTracker:NoSystemTracker, Timestamp:2018-12-04T22:42:12

I didn't find anywhere this error on official Microsoft Documentation.

Could someone tell me what does it means?

Thank you

Comment: Looks like the rule you're adding already exists.

Comment: I am not able to replicate the flow since I was thinking the same and i put a debug breakpont but is hitted just once when the error is thrown :(

Answer (score 2):

the rule you are adding is already there.Do `subscriptionClient.getRules()` to get all existing rules.
On our project at the creation of subscription client we first remove all existing rules and then add the rules we need. you might want to do that too

Comment: Thankyou so much man! you are a life saver, turned out I was trying to remove the wrong rule from subscription client and through your answer I first got all the Rules and then removed them one by one.. +1

Comment: should be like this 
`await subscriptionClient.RemoveRuleAsync(RuleDescription.DefaultRuleName);` for default rule